# What's the best dispatcher/callback library in Python?

Tags: python

I need to allow other Python applications to register callback functions for events in my application.  These need to have priorities associated with them (so a callback with a priority of 10 runs before a callback with a priority of 1) and callback functions need to be able to signal errors to the dispatcher.

These are all lightweight callbacks running in the same process, so I don't need to send signals across process boundaries.

Is there a good Python library to handle this, or do I need to write my own?

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115844/recommended-python-publishsubscribedispatch-module

Comment: @Florian: I think Chris is looking for libraries that will send events between two separate applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these other applications running in another address space? If so, you'll need to use an interprocess communication library like [D-BUS](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).

If you're just sending signals in the same process, try [PyDispatcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDispatcher/2.0.1)

Comment: Does PyDispatcher allow callers to set the priority of their methods?  Or return values?

Comment: No priority, but that's something you can write the signal registration function to perform. Not sure what you mean by return values -- I believe PyDispatcher returns the result of calling all the callbacks as a list.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you running under?  GObject is the basis of the GTK GUI that's widely-used under Linux, and it supports event loops with prioritizable events like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Twisted for anything network-related. Its perspective broker is quite nice to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try python-callbacks - http://code.google.com/p/python-callbacks/.