# Python: Callbacks, Delegates, ... ? What is common?

Tags: python, events, delegates, callback

Just want to know what's the common way to react on events in python. There are several ways in other languages like callback functions, delegates, listener-structures and so on. 
Is there a common way? Which default language concepts or additional modules are there and which can you recommend?

Answer (score 20):

Personally I don't see a difference between callbacks, listeners, and delegates.

The [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (a.k.a listeners, a.k.a "multiple callbacks") is easy to implement - just hold a list of observers, and add or remove callables from it. These callables can be functions, bound methods, or classes with the `__call__` magic method. All you have to do is define the interface you expect from these - e.g. do they receive any parameters.

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._bar_observers = []

  def add_bar_observer(self, observer):
    self._bar_observers.append(observer)

  def notify_bar(self, param):
    for observer in self._bar_observers:
      observer(param)

def observer(param):
  print "observer(%s)" % param

class Baz(object):
  def observer(self, param):
    print "Baz.observer(%s)" % param

class CallableClass(object):
  def __call__(self, param):
    print "CallableClass.__call__(%s)" % param

baz = Baz()

foo = Foo()

foo.add_bar_observer(observer) # function
foo.add_bar_observer(baz.observer) # bound method
foo.add_bar_observer(CallableClass()) # callable instance

foo.notify_bar(3)
```

Comment: nice example, but what about the '__call__' you mention, does it allow to register `foo.add_bar_observer(callable)` ?

Comment: @Kevin - added an example with `__call__`. You can read more about it (and other special method names) at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your update, `SomeCallable()` should read `SomeCallable` (I'm not sure enough to fix it myself, I'll remove the comment if necessary)

Comment: @Kevin - I believe the update is fine (and runs). It's instances of `SomeCallable` that are callable. I'll change the class name :)

Comment: would you explain why did you inherit from object ? and how notify_bar method knows which observer function/method is it calling ?

Comment: @Lucky inheriting from `object` is an ancient python2 quirk, ensuring we get new-style classes instead of old-style classes. Unnecessary in python3. notify_bar doesn't know or care which callable it's calling. It appended them to the list earlier, and now it's calling them. They're opaque as far as it's concerned.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for common approaches, but [this page](http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html) (actual copy is unavailable) has an implementation of the observer pattern that I like.

Here's the Internet Archive link:
http://web.archive.org/web/20060612061259/http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the level of complexity your application requires. For simple events, callbacks will probably do. For more complex patterns and decoupled levels you should use some kind of a publish-subscribe implementation, such as [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) or wxPython's pubsub.

See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115844/recommended-python-publish-subscribe-dispatch-module).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Python libraries I have used implement a callback model for their event notifications, which I think suits the language fairly well.  [Pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/) does this by deriving all objects from [GObject](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gobject.html), which implements callback-based signal handling.  (Although this is a feature of the underlying C GTK implementation, not something inspired by the language.)  However, [Pygtkmvc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtkmvc/) does an interesting job of implementing an observer pattern (and MVC) over the top of Pygtk.  It uses a very ornate metaclass based implementation, but I have found that it works fairly well for most cases.  The code is reasonably straightforward to follow, as well, if you are interested in seeing one way in which this has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've only seen callbacks used.  However, I haven't seen that much event driven python code so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen listeners and callbacks used. But AFAIK there is no Python way. They should be equally feasible if the application in question is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The `matplotlib.cbook` module contains a class `CallbackRegistry` that you might want to have a look at. From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/cbook_api.html):

```
Handle registering and disconnecting for a set of signals and
callbacks:

   signals = 'eat', 'drink', 'be merry'

   def oneat(x):
       print 'eat', x

   def ondrink(x):
       print 'drink', x

   callbacks = CallbackRegistry(signals)

   ideat = callbacks.connect('eat', oneat)
   iddrink = callbacks.connect('drink', ondrink)

   #tmp = callbacks.connect('drunk', ondrink) # this will raise a ValueError

   callbacks.process('drink', 123)    # will call oneat
   callbacks.process('eat', 456)      # will call ondrink
   callbacks.process('be merry', 456) # nothing will be called
   callbacks.disconnect(ideat)        # disconnect oneat
   callbacks.process('eat', 456)      # nothing will be called
```

You probably do not want a dependency to the matplotlib package. I suggest you simply copy-paste the class into your own module from the [source code](http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py?view=markup).

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for an implementation to register and handle events in Python. My only experience is with [Gobject](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gobject.html), but have only used it with PyGtk. It is flexible, but might be overly complicated for some users. I have come across of few other interesting candidates as well, but it's not clear how exactly they compare to one another.

- [Pyevent](http://code.google.com/p/pyevent/), a wrapper around [libevent](http://code.google.com/p/pyevent/).
- [Zope Event](http://code.google.com/p/pyevent/)